# How to know if my hosting service supports WebSockets

Tags: php, ssh, websocket, putty

I have a shared hosting plan (linux).
i followed a lot of guides and questions  guides:

[setting up websockets without command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888990/setting-up-websockets-without-command-line)

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-quickly-build-a-chat-app-with-ratchet/

and some others about connecting to SSH using Putty, phpShell,  etc, etc... 
A really lot of guides.

But nothing worked.
So, i am wondering if there is a way to know if my hosting service is blocking websockets or ssh connection or whatever i can use.

Comment: crazy idea, ask them

Comment: @rtfm *heh*, that'd almost be worthy as an answer; not so crazy an idea. I said "almost" ;-)

Comment: @Wiz did you ever thought about checking for errors also?

Comment: I changed the server direction (in client js), in this line:

var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
in a lot of options and kept getting  3 different errors from client when trying to connect to websockets:


-Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
- err_connection_reset
- connection_refused  (or something)

Comment: Shared hosting plans usually do not support webSockets because they require always on servers and constant connections and that messes up the shared server utilization model for shared hosting.  The only way to know for sure is to ask the hoster or find it in their doc.  Obviously if you implement it and it works, you know you're good, but if it doesn't work it will be hard to know if you have an implementation problem, a configuration problem or it's just not supported.  That you would have to find out from them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i just gave up with my hosting provider... 
moving on.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use c panel as they restrict such services due to shared hosting setup.

Comment: i dont understand what you are sugesting.

The only "useful"  option, for this case, i found in cpanel  was **ssh**
but when i tried to connect using putty, i got:  "network error: connection timed out"